# How to write xpath for this XDocument?

Tags: c#, xpath, linq-to-xml

```
    <tags>
    <data mode="add" name="ttt" oldindex="-1" index="-1" oldnumber="1" number="1"               type="VAR_INT" value="72" /> 
     <data mode="delete" name="test3d" oldindex="-1" index="-1" oldnumber="1" number="1"            type="VAR_INT" value="72" /> 
      </tags>
```

I want to check whether "mode" is present in xml or not

```
        xdDiffData.XPathSelectElement("//tags[@mode='add']") != null &&        xdDiffData.XPathSelectElement("//tags[@mode='delete']") != null
```

This always gives false..how to do this... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the 'data' element. Try

```
xdDiffData.XPathSelectElement("//tags/data[@mode='add']") != null &&        xdDiffData.XPathSelectElement("//tags/data[@mode='delete']") != null
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make sure that `mode` attribute is present in every `data` element, then you should better iterate all the data elements to look for the `mode` attribute this way:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("XmlFile.xml");
var nodes = doc.Descendants("data");

foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    var attrMode = node.Attribute("mode");
    if (attrMode == null)
    {
        // mode attribute is not available for this data element
    }
}
```

Using Linq:

```
if (nodes.Where(c => c.Attribute("mode") == null).Count() == 0)
{
    var result = nodes.All(e => 
                           e.Attribute("mode").Value.Equals("add") ||
                           e.Attribute("mode").Value.Equals("delete"));
} 
else
{
    // 'mode' attribute is missing for one or more 'data' element(s)
}
```

If `result` equals to `true`, then it means all the data elements have `mode` attribute either set to value `"add"` or `"delete"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    xdDiffData.XPathSelectElement("/tags/data[@mode='add']") != null
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to check whether "mode" is present in xml or not

**Use**:

```
//@mode
```

if this XPath expression selects a node, this means that an attribute named `mode` is present in the XML document.

**or you could use**:

```
boolean(//@mode)
```

and this produces a boolean value -- `true()` or `false()`